# Why Retrofit2 works with @Field and not @Body for POST requests

Tags: java, php, android, json, retrofit2

I don't understand the difference, I have coded an example where my application sends username and password to the server using a POST request using retrofit2.

I first tried sending the request with @Body tag in the interface method:`

```
@POST("/testproject/login.php")
Call<TestResponse> sendUsernamePassword(@Body UserData userData);
```

But my login.php responded with no body tags(username,password) received.

Then I change the method to send request using FormEncoding:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/testproject/login.php")
Call<TestResponse> sendUsernamePassword(@Field("username")String username, 
                                        @Field("password")String password);
```

And it started working, But I don't understand why retrofit couldn't send post request using @Body annotation.

Here is `login.php` file

```
<?php

   if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

      $response['status']   = 'success';
      $response['username'] = $_POST['username'] . " received";
      $response['password'] = $_POST['password'] . "received";

      echo json_encode($response);
   } else {
      $response['status'] = 'failure';
      echo json_encode($response);
   }

?>
```

Can someone explain what's the difference and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@Body` – Sends Java objects as request body.

`@Field` – Send data as form-urlencoded. The @Field parameter works only with a POST.

In order to read POST json body in php, you can use the following code:

```
//Get the request body
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
//Convert into array
$input = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE);

$username = $input['username'];
$password = $input['password'];
```

Comment: is there anyway I can put checks on whether the data is received by `file_get_contents('php://input')` and how do I make sure this method is not called every time I hit the url.
I am very new to this so a little help will be appreciated, thanks.